# Adding column dynamically in Temp table in Ms Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

In Sql server, i write a procedure and i use one tem table and a cursor and dynamically add one column to that temporary table but it is giving erro :

```
(10 row(s) affected)
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_F_Roll_AllIndia_Report, Line 27
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

This is my proc :

```
alter procedure USP_F_Roll_AllIndia_Report       
(@segcode int,@rollplanyear int)
as
 begin
declare @cfcode varchar(10)
declare @cfname varchar(30)
declare @SQl nvarchar(max)  

create table #TEP (productcode varchar(10) collate database_default,proddesc varchar(100))

declare db_cursor cursor for   

select distinct canfm.CFCode, SUBSTRING (CANFM.CFName,4,5)as CFName   from Tbl_F_CandF_M CANFM left outer join   Tbl_F_Org_CandF_T CT  on  CANFM.CFCode = ct.CFCode where  CANFM .status =1 and ct.Status =1 order by canfm.cfcode   

open db_cursor 

fetch next from db_cursor into @cfcode, @cfname

while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
  begin

    set @SQL ='alter table #TEP add '+@cfname+' float'  
    exec sp_executesql @Sql
    --exec  ( @Sql)


    insert into #TEP 

    select pd.productcode,PM.productdesc,convert(varchar,sum(isnull(AmendedQty,isnull(Quantity,0))))as quantity    from Tbl_F_Roll_PlanDetails_T pd left outer join Tbl_F_ProductMaster_M PM on
    pd.ProductCode =pm.ProductCode left outer join Tbl_F_CandF_M CANDF on pd.CandFLocation =CANDF.CFCode    where pd. RollPlanYear =@rollplanyear and pd.CandFLocation =@cfcode  and  pd.ProductCode in (
    select ProductCode  from   Tbl_F_Segment_Product_t where SegCode  =@segcode )    group by pd.ProductCode,pm.ProductDesc  

   fetch next from db_cursor into @cfcode, @cfname
 end              
     close db_cursor              
     deallocate db_cursor                                             
     select * from #TEP               
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will not work . if you are adding column then your select query in insert statement must be a dynamic one since it will keep adding column .

you can create a dynamic query for insert and in select as well.
you will also need to specify columns names like
insert into #TEP (col1,clo2,col3..)

there might be better ways for your requiremnet if you specify them .
cursor and adding column is not good logic.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as you're trying to. SQL Server is trying to compile the entire batch as early as possible - it compiles the `insert` once your `create table` has executed, and at that time, there are 2 columns in the table, but 3 in the insert.

But, stop and think about it further - even if it worked the first time through the loop, what happens the next time through your loop? At that point, there are *4* columns in your table, but still only 3 in the insert. I can't remember if that will fail completely, or just insert into the first additional column you've added to the table, but either way, I'm almost certain it's not what you want.

---

It looks like you're trying to do some form of pivot with an unknown number of columns - there are plenty of questions and answers on SO about doing that already. You have to go down the route of dynamic SQL (even more so than what you've attempted), and it's never pretty. I'd almost always recommend returning a normal result set (e.g. fixed number of columns) to another system (code, report generator, etc) which is better suited to do that kind of mucking about with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are adding a new column on each loop, but the insert statement has a static number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why this isn't working for you but

I'm Running `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` AND the following is working fine with me

```
 CREATE TABLE #temp (ID int) 
 DECLARE @Sql as varchar(250) 
 DECLARE @colName varchar(50)
  SET @colName  = 'name'
  SET @Sql = 'ALTER TABLE #temp ADD [' + @colName + '] VARCHAR(50)'
  EXEC (@Sql)
  SELECT * FROM #temp 
 DROP TABLE #temp
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/279)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @colname varchar(max)='col1,col2,col3',@sqlq varchar(max)=''
  Declare @tblname  varchar(max)='tbl1' 
   set @sqlq='Select '+@colname+' from  table tbl_DefaultPermission  '

EXECUTE (@sqlq)
```

Comment: Posting code without any explanation isn't welcome here. Would you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51148245/edit) your post ?